# Missing error description failed after image upload attempt

Tags: bug, images, error-message, uploader

Missing error description after failed image upload attempt (there is a ":" followed by )

[image: The upload dialog showing "An error occured when uploading the image:", followed by nothing]

Comment: I tried uploading a renamed .txt file and a .webp file (even a .tiff, but while the icon broke it accepted and converted the file to .jpg) but wasn't able to [reproduce this on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aUGH.jpg). --- Which browser did you use, and which file extension did you try to upload?

Comment: @Rob .png or .jpg, was a one-time issue.

Comment: Was there text there that wasn't visible (maybe black text on black background) or was there no text there at all?

Comment: @BSMP idk but my guess is no text.

Comment: This is easily reproducible by turning off the internet before uploading the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV6z8.png (Chrome, Windows 11).

Comment: The colon *is* confusing though. I asked about it here: [Incorrect(?) punctuation in the error message: "An error occurred when uploading the image:"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379116/incorrect-punctuation-in-the-error-message-an-error-occurred-when-uploading) (Deleted)